# How to make JQuery DatePicker work after dynamically loaded in a partial view?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have lost jquery datepicker functionality in this scenario...

1- Originally I had a normal view, which worked fine, having this code for date input...

```
<input type="text" name="date_start" id="date_start"
                       value="@(Model.TimeStart)" />
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $("#date_start").datepicker();
</script>
```

2- Then, I converted that view in a partial view which is dynamically loaded with...

```
$('#TargetEmptyDiv').load("/MyController/MyAction");
```

3- The partial view loads ok, the data can be (manually) entered and all its fine. The only problem is that the jquery datepicker is no longer working. I tryed to assign it after the loading, using this...

```
$('#TargetEmptyDiv').load("/MyController/MyAction",
                          function () { $("#date_start").datepicker(); });
```

That did not work.

4- Later I've learned that jquery provides the live() and delegate() functions which are capable of attach javascript code to elements loaded "now and in the future". So, I tryed this in the document initialization...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
           $("#date_start").live("click", function () { $(this).datepicker(); });
    });
</script>
```

and later also...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
           $("#date_start").delegate("click", function () { $(this).datepicker(); });
    });
</script>
```

none of which worked, maybe because they directly reference to the "click" event, but the datepicker is "attached" (if that is the proper term) to the whole element.

So, question is:
How to make the jquery datepicker work on elements loaded after dynamic load???

Thanks for your time!

SOLVED:
The problem was that at the bottom of _Layout.cshtml there is this line...

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
```

..which loads the minified version of jquery libraries (already referenced by myself).
So, the libraries were loaded twice and got invalid, producing the error "datepicker() is not a function".

Just commenting or deleting that line, makes all work fine!

Comment: Just to start simple, have you included jquery.ui to make sure datepicker is available?

Comment: What didn't work in `3`?

Comment: Do you have more than one element with ID of `date_start`?

Comment: Assigning the datepicker on a click event is probably not a very good idea because you will do that multiple times and it could cause issues or errors. undefined makes a good point about the unique id issue.

Comment: jquery.ui referenced. The datepicker did work ok before the elements were dynamically loaded in a partial view.

Comment: What didn't work in 3 whas the jquery datepicker dialog box (not shown).

Comment: @NéstorSánchezA. Try this `$("[id=date_start]").datepicker();` If this works for you, you should change IDs to classes.

Comment: your code works fine here [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wirey00/v36KG/)

Comment: did you try to call the script directly from the partial?

Answer (score 4):

Put the following jQuery in the base view, not the partial view

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () { 
      $(document).on('focus', '.datefield', function () {
          $(this).datepicker();
      });
  });
</script>
```

This will work when a partial view is dynamically loaded and on page load.

Answer (score 3):

Your approach in #3 looks to me like it should have worked, so it seems like you need to do some debugging.  Try this:

1. Get the Firebug extension, if you use Firefox (Chrome has dev tools built in)
2. Add a `debugger` line to your code (see below for example)
3. Load your page up with Chrome or Firebug/Firefox (or any other browser's dev tools)

What should happen is that your browser will pause at that point.  However, if things aren't working as you expect, it might not be hitting that code at all, and then you'd get no pause.

If you do get a pause, use the console to inspect the value of `$("#date_start")`; it's possible that jQuery selector isn't grabbing what you think it is.

Here's a `debugger` example with your code:

```
$('#TargetEmptyDiv').load("/MyController/MyAction", function () {
    debugger;
    $("#date_start").datepicker();
});
```

Comment: The debugger shows "undefined" when pointing (with the mouse cursor) over the "datepicker()" function.

Comment: Aha!  So what that means is that, whatever `$("#date_start")` is, it has no datepicker method.  There *could* be other reasons for that, but the most likely reason is that something went wrong with your jQuery UI-inclusion script tag.  Maybe it's worth double-checking the path on that tag?  Also, this may sound stupid, but with jQuery UI you can download versions of the library without certain parts; are you sure your copy has the date picker?

Comment: Oh, just thought of one other possibility: if your code looks like this `<script src='yourCode.js'></script><script src='jQueryUI.js'></script>` then jQuery UI might not be loaded by the time your code runs.  If that's the case, switching the order of the script tags should fix you.

Answer (score 3):

On your partial page say "/MyController/MyAction",

Partial Page Code:

```
<div>
    <form>
        <!--Other Elements-->
        <input type="text" id="adate" name="adate" title="date" />
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){    
            $( "#adate" ).datepicker();
        });
     </script>
</div>
```

Full Page(Page From Where You are Calling Ajax Request) Code:

```
<div id="TargetEmptyDiv"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function abc(){
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/MyController/MyAction",
        success: function(response)
        { 
            $("#TargetEmptyDiv").html(response);
        }
 });
}
</script>
```

call function abc and you are done.assuming you already have all jquery files loaded.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the Id of the date field that I tried to hook up the datepicker to was not what I thought it was. I am using ViewModels and the id got prefixed with the ViewModel name of my partial view.

machineghost's answer put me on to it.

So I now use Charly's answer but instead of #BirthDate I have #IdentityModel_BirthDate:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () { 
      $(document).on('focus', '#IdentityModel_BirthDate', function () {
          $(this).datepicker({
              format: 'MM/dd/yyyy',
              changeMonth: true,
              changeYear: true,
              yearRange: "-90:+0"
          });
      });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need to make the datepicker work is steps 1-3.

Here's a sample:
http://jsfiddle.net/delrosario/Xd8py/

You got datepicker to work without loading the markup dynamically and your pseudo code for the dynamic version is sound from steps 1-3. The thing you need to check now is to make sure that your dependencies are being loaded before your main program (in this case make sure that jquery and jquery ui are available before running the request + datepicker setup).

1) load jquery
2) load jquery ui
3) wait till the dom is ready or the element that will contain your payload is ready
4) execute your main app that does steps 1-3 from your description.

So it would be something like this.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="path-jquery-ui-css" />
    <script src="path-to-jquery"></script>
    <script src="path-to-jquery-ui"></script>
    <script id="main_app">
      (function () {
        // wait till dom is ready before executing our code,
        // in this case steps 1-3.
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="datepicker_target">datepicker target</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

After invoking ajax, hookup your jquery to the 'ajaxStop' event.  (SEE: '@section Scripts' )

$(document).ajaxStop handles the post ajax jquery call and now datapicker works after ajax call(s).  yea...

**Note:** $(document).ready... handles the initial page load datapicker decoration, but after an ajax form reload, datepicker jquery was not executed...

```
@model Q_Admin.Models.AllQAViewModel

<div id="mainContent">

  @using (Ajax.BeginForm("EAAll","Answer",new AjaxOptions {
    UpdateTargetId = "mainContent",
    HttpMethod = "POST",
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace
  }))

  for (int i = 0; i < Model.VMs.Count; i++)
  { 
   @switch (Model.QAVMs[i].qN.Node1.TypeAnswer.AnswerType.Trim().ToUpper())
   {
    case "DATETIME":
      @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.VMs[i].CurrentNodeText, 
            new { @class = "datepicker", @id = "datepicker" });
      break;
    case "DROPDOWNLIST":
         @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.QAVMs[i].AnswerRecord.AnswerID,
           new SelectList(Model.QAVMs[i].answerNodes, "ID", "NodeText.Text", Model.QAVMs[i].SelectedNodeID),
          "-- Select an Answer --",
           new { @onchange = "$(this).parents('form:first').find(':submit')[0].click();"   }) }
      break;
    default:
       break;
    }
  }
</div>

@section Scripts{
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // debugger;
        $("#datepicker").datepicker(
            {
                dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy",
                constrainInput: true
            });
    });
    $(document).ajaxStop(function () {
        // debugger;
        $("#datepicker").datepicker(
            {
                dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy",
                constrainInput: true
            });
    });
</script>}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem before.  In my situation I had `<script src='jQueryUI.js'></script>` referenced at the bottom of the page.  Moving the reference to the top of page fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like #3 should works. But maybe you can try a hacky way like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(this).on("mousedown", "#date_start", function (e) { 
             $(this).datepicker(); e.preventDefault();$(this).click(); 
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: The Firefox debugger says "$(...).datepicker is not a function".

Answer (score 0):

I have this working

Action Method:

```
public ActionResult GetControl()
{
    return View("_partial");
}
```

Main View:

```
<div id="TargetEmptyDiv"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#TargetEmptyDiv').load("/Home/GetControl");
    });
</script>
```

Partial View:

```
@{
    Layout = "";
}

<input type="text" name="date_start" id="date_start" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#date_start").datepicker();
    });
</script>
```

Of course you have to remember to include jquery-ui.js in your Layout

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.20.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

My suspicion is that your JS is executing, but you have improperly referenced jquery-ui.  I recommend adding all jquery libraries at a higher level than a partial view.  Try putting the `<script src="jquery-ui.js">` tag in either the page or the layout, not the partial view.  If this doesn't fix it, try putting `alert("test");` in your javascript code to make sure that it is executing.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem. If using ajax, then bind the below jquery function to the document. Each time ajax is executed, this will fire. Check out the api doc here - http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/

$(document).ajaxComplete(function (){//your code here})

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, solved using a previous version of `JQuery-UI`. In my case goes to use the version `1.9.2` and `1.10.3` to `JQuery` version `1.10.1`. Know the reason, but I think the latest versions bring some problems compactness, so I chose to use always backward to the past.
I hope it will be useful

Answer (score -1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">$(function () {$("#datefield").datepicker();});</script>
```

just load this line with the content you have to load by ajax

Answer (score -1):

hi: you put below code in load document event script tag in your partial view :

```
$(function(){

$("#date_start").datepicker();

})
```